# Laravel exception I cannot get rid of: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::filter()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm following the "Code Bright" book examples (Laravel 4), but also trying out a few little modifications of my own.

When I started trying the **class filters** I started to get this exception: **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::filter()** with any filter I have in app/filters.php (even with the filters provided by default like "auth"). The first in the file which is not commented out throws the exception.

I cannot get rid of it despite I rolled back to not autoload the custom filter classes folder, named app/filters. Of course I used "composer dump-autoload" everytime I changed composer.json.

What must be triggering this exception? I don't get much info from the debug backtrace.

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: Can you paste your `app.php` config file and your `composer.json` file?

Comment: Ooops! Since I wanted to get it working again, I've just made a hard reset to the application just when it was installed, and next with the routes I used previously in the tutorial pasted and commited. Is it possible to go forth to my last commit before the reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it.

Resetted to the initial state of the application, and created again the filter. I've followed the same steps and I'm quite sure everything was the same when the error was being triggered. But nothing wrong is happening now. I have no idea what was interfering and raising the error. All I had before was simple routes and other simple filters.

Filter class:

```
// app/filters/filtermyclassfilter.php
class FilterMyClassFilter
{
    public function filter($route, $request)
    {
        if (date('m') >= 7 && date('m') <= 9) {
            return 'the filter has been triggered'; 
        }
    }
}
```

composer.json (note the "app/filters" line in "autoload")

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/filters",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Filter alias:

```
// app/filters.php
Route::filter('classfilter', 'FilterMyClassFilter');
```

Route assigned to filter:

```
// app/routes.php
Route::get('/pathtoclassfilter', array(
    'before'    => 'classfilter', 
    function() {
        return 'Filter not triggered!!';
    }
));
```